# Can Jest Suppress Console Output Except on Test Failure When Testing?

Tags: testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm interested in testing the `foo` function with Jest. This function contains a `console.log` statement within it. Is it feasible to configure Jest so that it only displays the `console.log` output when a test fails?

```
function foo() {
  ...
  console.log(...);
  ...
}

describe('....', () => {
  test(`...`, () => {
    const results = foo();
    expect(.........); 
  });
```